# Use Call Activity without logging in recent calls

Tags: java, android, security, logging, android-activity

I have an application that uses call activity to call people. However, when the call is made, the number will be logged to recent call list, and I don't want this to happen.

What would be the best way for the phone to not to log the calls made?

Comment: This is almost certainly not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if the recent call list uses the same database as the call log, however if it does you can just delete the call from that content provider after it is made.

Take a look at this: http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/androidcalllogdeletion/

Comment: I haven't tried implementing this yet, but this is great starting point for me. thx. Will report back to this comment if it actually does allow me to modify recent call list